# replace null or empty data in string builder with some message

Tags: java

I have a string builder and it contains some data.I want to ensure whenever there is a null or empty("") data in it, i want to replace it with some message e.g not available. This is a huge data and i cannot go and replace each and every String.
Following is a snippet of code :

```
Stringbuilder sb = new Stringbuilder();
String a = "10";
String b = 13;
sb.append("entity.id=").append(a).append("entity.value=").append(b);
sb.toString;
```

So whenever entity.id or entity."ANYTHING" equals "null" or is empty, it should be replaced with a message like entity.id= not available

Comment: If you cannot replace in the buffer, then you have to check the values before appending them to that buffer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a function, for example...

```
public String checkString(String str) {
 if(str == null || str.isEmpty())
  return "N/A";
 return str;
}
```

Call it on a String you want to append.

`sb.append("entity.id=").append(checkString(a)).append("entity.value=").append(checkString(b));`

Answer (score 3):

Without knowing your exact requirements, this may not be perfect, but is one option:

```
public void myCustomAppend(Appendable a, CharSequence cs){
  if(cs == null || cs.length() == 0){
    a.append("(not available)");
  }else{
    a.append(cs);
  }
}

myCustomAppend(sb, "entity.id=");
myCustomAppend(sb, a);
myCustomAppend(sb, "entity.value=");
myCustomAppend(sb, b);
```

Some improvements to this could include creating it as a custom object with it's own state - preventing the need to keep passing-in the same reference to the StringBuilder, as well as allowing for successive calls to be chained (as you had them in the original question).

Answer (score 1):

Consider using Guava's [Joiner](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Joiner.html) class.

```
List<String> values = newArrayList("value1", "value2", a, b, c);
String result = Joinger.on(" ").useForNull("null").join(values);
```

You can also use "omitNull" instead of "useForNull"

Seeing what you are doing, you might also want to look at [MoreObjects.ToStringHelper](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Objects.ToStringHelper.html)

[Guava docs](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Joiner.html)

Answer (score 0):

check the strings if they are empty, before you append it. If the string is empty you can append a your message instead of the content of the data strings. ;)